# What DateTime formats are valid for <time> elements?

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

The [HTML5 spec for the `<time>` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-time-element) lists a number of formats that are valid for the element's "datetime value".

What string formats can be used to format `DateTime` objects such that they are valid "datetime values"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A valid month string

- 2011-11
  `"yyyy-MM"`

### A valid date string

- 2011-11-12
  `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

### A valid yearless date string

- 11-12
  `"MM-dd"`

### A valid time string

- 14:54
  `"H:mm"`
- 14:54:39
  `"H:mm:ss"`
- 14:54:39.929
  `"H:mm:ss.fff"`

### A valid local date and time string

- 2011-11-12T14:54
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm"`
- 2011-11-12T14:54:39
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss"`
- 2011-11-12T14:54:39.929
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fff"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54:39
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54:39.929
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.fff"`

### A valid time-zone offset string

- Z
  `"K"`
- +0000
- +00:00
  `"zzz"`
- -0800
- -08:00
  `"zzz"`

### A valid global date and time string

- 2011-11-12T14:54Z
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mmK"`
- 2011-11-12T14:54:39Z
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ssK"`
- 2011-11-12T14:54:39.929Z
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fffK"`
- 2011-11-12T14:54+0000
- 2011-11-12T14:54:39+0000
- 2011-11-12T14:54:39.929+0000
- 2011-11-12T14:54+00:00
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mmzzz"`
- 2011-11-12T14:54:39+00:00
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:sszzz"`
- 2011-11-12T14:54:39.929+00:00
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fffzzz"`
- 2011-11-12T06:54-0800
- 2011-11-12T06:54:39-0800
- 2011-11-12T06:54:39.929-0800
- 2011-11-12T06:54-08:00
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz"`
- 2011-11-12T06:54:39-08:00
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"`
- 2011-11-12T06:54:39.929-08:00
  `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54Z
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mmK"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54:39Z
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ssK"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54:39.929Z
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss:fffK"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54+0000
- 2011-11-12 14:54:39+0000
- 2011-11-12 14:54:39.929+0000
- 2011-11-12 14:54+00:00
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mmzzz"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54:39+00:00
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:sszzz"`
- 2011-11-12 14:54:39.929+00:00
  `"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.fffzzz"`
- 2011-11-12 06:54-0800
- 2011-11-12 06:54:39-0800
- 2011-11-12 06:54:39.929-0800
- 2011-11-12 06:54-08:00
  `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmzzz"`
- 2011-11-12 06:54:39-08:00
  `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszzz"`
- 2011-11-12 06:54:39.929-08:00
  `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffzzz"`

### A valid week string

- 2011-W46

### Four or more ASCII digits, at least one of which is not "0" (U+0030)

- 2011
  `"yyyy"`

### A valid duration string

- PT4H18M3S
- 4h 18m 3s